# OpenCV: conversion MatOfDMatch,MatOfPoint2f, MatOfKeypoint, aaproach to find FundamentalMatrix

Tags: android, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

its may be a simple / stupid question, but I have a conversion problem in opencv (android).

my goal is to calculate the fundamentalMatrix out of corresponding matches from two consecutive images.

i programmed this so far (and working):

```
detector.detect(actImg, actKP);
detector.detect(prevImg, prevKP);
descExtractor.compute(prevImg, prevKP, descriptorPrev);
descExtractor.compute(actImg, actKP, descriptorAct);
descMatcher.match(descriptorPrev, descriptorAct, matches);
Features2d.drawMatches(prevImg, prevKP, actImg, actKP,matches, mRgba);
```

matches are of the type MatOfDMatch.

now i would calculate the fundamentalMatrix out of the points that matches against each other. therefor i must know which of the keypoints in the first image (prevKP) were found in the second image (actKP).

```
Mat fundamental_matrix = Calib3d.findFundamentalMat(nextPts, prevPts, Calib3d.FM_RANSAC,3, 0.99);
```

first question:
how can i extract / convert MatOfKeyPoints to MatOfPoint2f (that they can be passed to findFundamentalMatrix)

second question:
how to pass only the matched keypoints to the function findFundamentalMatrix.
is this a good way of doing it?

thanks a lot in advace!

**EDIT**

thanks a lot for your detailed response!
i wrote your code into two functions:

```
private MatOfPoint2f getMatOfPoint2fFromDMatchesTrain(MatOfDMatch matches2,
        MatOfKeyPoint prevKP2) {
    DMatch dm[] = matches2.toArray();
    List<Point> lp1 = new ArrayList<Point>(dm.length);
    KeyPoint tkp[] = prevKP2.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < dm.length; i++) {
        DMatch dmm = dm[i];
        if (dmm.trainIdx < tkp.length) 
            lp1.add(tkp[dmm.trainIdx].pt);
    }
    return new MatOfPoint2f(lp1.toArray(new Point[0]));
}

private MatOfPoint2f getMatOfPoint2fFromDMatchesQuery(MatOfDMatch matches2,
        MatOfKeyPoint actKP2) {
    DMatch dm[] = matches2.toArray();
    List<Point> lp2 = new ArrayList<Point>(dm.length);
    KeyPoint qkp[] = actKP2.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < dm.length; i++) {
        DMatch dmm = dm[i];
        if (dmm.queryIdx < qkp.length)
            lp2.add(qkp[dmm.queryIdx].pt);
    }
    return new MatOfPoint2f(lp2.toArray(new Point[0]));
}
```

but when i am calling

```
prevPts = getMatOfPoint2fFromDMatchesTrain(matches, prevKP);
nextPts = getMatOfPoint2fFromDMatchesQuery(matches, actKP);
Mat fundamental_matrix = Calib3d.findFundamentalMat(
        nextPts, prevPts, Calib3d.FM_RANSAC, 3, 0.99);
```

the problem is that i get the error -215. 
the error:

> *error: (-215) npoints >= 0 && points2.checkVector(2) == npoints && points1.type() == points2.type() in function cv::Mat
>   cv::findFundamentalMat(...*

i proved that prevPts and nextPts arend below 10 points (for ransac). 
so i would guess that the error is that the points arend floating points. but i checked this with the debugger that these points are floating points.

your suggested codeline:

```
return new MatOfPoint2f(lp2.toArray(new Point[0]));
```

should convert the points to floating point or am i wrong?

thanks again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no better way (even in C++ API) than loop through all matches and copy values to new Mat (or vector).

In Java you can do it as follows:

```
DMatch dm[] = matches.toArray();
List<Point> lp1 = new ArrayList<Point>(dm.length);
List<Point> lp2 = new ArrayList<Point>(dm.length);
KeyPoint tkp[] = prevKP.toArray();
KeyPoint qkp[] = actKP.toArray();
for (int i = 0; i < dm.length; i++) {
    DMatch dm = dm[i];
    lp1.add(tkp[dm.trainIdx].pt);
    lp2.add(qkp[dm.queryIdx].pt);
}

MatOfPoint2f pointsPrev = new MatOfPoint2f(lp1.toArray(new Point[0]));
MatOfPoint2f pointsAct  = new MatOfPoint2f(lp2.toArray(new Point[0]));
```

Comment: thank you for your good code! do you have any idea whats the problem with the call of the findFundamentalMatrix?

Comment: Probably you are having a few matches. `findFundamentalMat` requires at least 8 point pairs to work (but more is better).

Comment: i prove that there are more than ten items in both lists, so this couldn't be the problem. any other suggestions?

Comment: the problem wasn't the function "findfundamentalMatrix" but the function drawMatches - thank you again!